# Why does an ActiveRecord object return DateTime.now differently than DateTime.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say I have a simple ActiveRecord model with this example schema:

```
  create_table "users", id: :serial do |t|
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

When I run the following code in the console:

```
user = User.new
user.updated_at = DateTime.now
user.updated_at # => Thu, 27 Feb 2020 09:28:51 GMT +00:00
```

My question is: why this output is different than the normal return value of `DateTime.now`, which is

```
DateTime.now # => Thu, 27 Feb 2020 10:28:51 +0100
```

Is there some kind of serializer involved? How can I find out more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AR updated_at/created_at are time zone aware attributes. You can read more about them here:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

If you grab a User record for instance, and call `time_zone_aware_types` on it, you'll get the timezone aware column types

```
user = User.first
user.time_zone_aware_types

=> [:datetime, :time]
```

These types of columns are automatically converted to `Time.zone` when retrieved from the database even though they are stored in UTC.

The difference with `DateTime.now` is that it's not timezone aware and just returns the time in UTC

Comment: We have three types of times system time, application time and selected time.
DateTime.now uses your system time and Objects use Application Time.

Answer (score 0):

add your time zone in your config/application.rb inside the

```
class Application < Rails::Application

.......
# it will be like this
    config.time_zone = "Asia/Riyadh"
.....
end
```